# Update deprecated FilesystemCache to FilesystemAdapter in Symfony

Tags: symfony, caching

im trying to update my code to stop using FilesystemCache but after update to FilesystemAdapter it cannot found existing keys;

In old code i retrieve cache like that:

```
  use Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache;

  $filesystemCached = new FilesystemCache(
        'oauth', 0,
        $projectDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'var' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'log'
    );

 
    if ($filesystemCached->has('someKey')) {
        $someKey = $filesystemCached->get('someKey');
    }
```

I have existing files in this directory so key is found. After migrate to FilesystemAdapter with this code:

```
  use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter;

  $filesystemCached = new FilesystemAdapter(
        'oauth', 0,
        $projectDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'var' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'log'
    );


    $refreshTokenItem = $filesystemCached->getItem('someKey');

    if ($refreshTokenItem->isHit()) {
        $someKey = $refreshTokenItem->get();
    }
```

It not found existing key. If i add the same key, cache creating new files, not using old.

[image: Cache location]

New file content is the same as old.

How can i fix it? I must have access to old cache.

Comment: I resolved this problem using simple-cache-bridge:
https://packagist.org/packages/cache/simple-cache-bridge

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is unfortunate but expected behavior. If you look at how the file is generated you will notice this line in `vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php` which is called by both implementations:

```php
$hash = str_replace('/', '-', base64_encode(hash('md5', static::class.$id, true)));
```

The issue is with `static::class` which will refer to the class implementing the trait, so either `FilesystemCache` or `FilesystemAdapter`, which will lead to different hashes. This will make sure the caches do not collide if you use them both in parallel.

You could create a chain adapter with both adapters in there to make sure that the keys are transferred over to the new filesystem cache, while still being able to read from the old filesystem cache and then with a later release disable the old filesystem cache. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/chain_adapter.html